# Run batch file on remote pc *visibly* to logged on user

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vlc, adhoc, dmx512

I've got a batch file dmx2vlc which will play a random video file through VLC-Player when called.
It works well locally but I need this to happen on another machine on the network (will be adhoc) and the result (VLC-Player playing the video) must be visible on the remote screen.
I've tried SSH, Powershell and PsExec, but both seem to run the batch file and the player in the session of the command line, even when applying a patch to allow multiple logins.

So IF I get to run the batch file it is never visible on screen.
Using Teamviewer and the like is no option as I need to be able to call all this programmatically from my dmx program.

I'm not bound to being able to call the batch directly, it would be sufficient for me if I could somehow trigger it to run.

Sadly latency is a problem here as we are talking about a lighting (thus dmx) environment.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PSexec if the remote system is XP with the interactive parameter if you state the session to interact with, 0 would probably be the console (person physically in front of the machine).
This has issues with Windows Vista and newer as it pops up a prompt to ask the user to change their display mode first.

From memory, you could create a scheduled task on the remote system pretty easily though and as long as it's interactive the user should see it.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup about the -i parameter. I got it to work but I had to follow [these instructions](http://superuser.com/a/301872/377331) in addition.
Even though I can now control the video output this way, it turns out to be quite slow and I might be looking at how to solve this by listening to MIDI notes.

Anyhow - thank you very much!

Comment: By the way: -i works like a charm here (calling on win8, client on win7).

Answer (score 1):

Try using web interface. It is rather easy: VLC is running http server, and accessing particular URL from remote machine will give full control over VLC. Documentation can be found [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Alternative_Interfaces/)